# Finishing the soap call before moving to the next line of code

Tags: angularjs

I am making a soap call in angular as below

```
app.factory('service', ['$soap', function ($soap) {
return {
    SampleRequest: function (param1,param2) {
        return $soap.post(url, "SampleRequest", {
            'Request': {
                'input1': param1,
                'input2': param2,
            }});
    }
}
}])
```

I am defined it as below for invoking the webservice

```
$rootScope.callSoapService = function () {
service.SampleRequest("Hello","World").then(function (response) {
        if (response.Valid == 'Y') {
           //do something
        }
}
}
```

and defined it like this

```
function callService() {
    $rootScope.callSoapService();
}
```

Now my question when I do something like below

```
$rootScope.dosomething = function(){
 function1();
 callService();
 function2();
}
```

the problem was function1 executes and returns and goes to the next line callService where it wont finish the call but executes the next line which was function2() and then finally executes the soap request . Is there any way to make it to execute in sequence ?

Comment: Yup, it's asynchronous code. There's no way to make it block (thankfully), so you need to learn to use promises. Try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17522010/854556

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Javascript to wait for an asynchronous call before proceeding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521920/how-to-get-javascript-to-wait-for-an-asynchronous-call-before-proceeding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests are asynchronous, you should work with promises when you need to synchronize work. Assuming `callService` returns a "promise", you can simply do:

```
$rootScope.dosomething = function(){
    function1();
    callService().then(() => {
        function2();
    });
}
```